# A containment result in complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

A question on the interesting result in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6126v1.pdf

It is shown $\Pi_2^P \not\subset P^{NP}$. But http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy says $\Pi_2^P = CoNP^{NP}$.

Does this mean an oracle in NP under which $P$ is not $CoNP$ has been shown?

Could someone elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aaronson's result shows that $\Pi_2 \not\subset P^{N\!P}$ relative to a random oracle with probability 1. As he mentions, it had already been known that $N\! P != \mathrm{co}N\! P$ (and so $P \neq N\!P$ and $P \neq \mathrm{co}N\!P$) relative to a random oracle with probability 1: see the paper by [Bennett and Gill](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210008). An oracle with respect to which $P \neq N\!P$ (and so $P \neq \mathrm{co}N\!P$) had been constructed earlier by [Baker, Gill and Solovay](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0204037). The construction is standard, and you can find [many references](https://www.google.com/search?q=baker%20gill%20solovay) online.

Comment: Thankyou, but he also mentions "....random oracle, but the highest levels of PH previously proved separate were NP and coNP." could you elaborate this statement within the context of the question?

Comment: NP and coNP were only separated relative to a random oracle. If NP$\neq$coNP then P$\neq$NP. If there were an oracle $O \in N\!P$ such that $P^O \neq \mathrm{co}N\!P^O$ then also P$\neq$NP (if $O \in P$ then $P^O = P = \mathrm{co}N\!P^O$).